# How do I rectify swear (kasam) I took of my parents in anger?

Tags: karma

Recently I was fighting with someone and I got way too angry and told that person that I swear on my parents and my career that I won't ever talk to you... But it isn't possible for stop talking as we are in same college and classes and it's impossible to not even say a word.. Help

Comment: Sad. Btw, God won't take you seriously. He knows Kali people very well. They are not capable to observe anything.  Btw, personal advices are not allowed in this site. You can reformat your details.

Comment: once you have made a swear then try to keep it and it may also satisfies your soul that you made a proper decision.

Comment: Personal advice questions are offtopic.